# Adding Quotes in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization

Is there a straightforward way in Swift for adding **quotation marks** to a String? The quotation marks should localize properly (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark) based on the user's language settings. I'd like to show the string in a UILabel after adding the quotes.

For instance:

```
var quote: String!
quote = "To be or not to be..."
// one or more lines of code that add localized quotation marks
```

For a French user: *«To be or not to be...»*

For a German user: *„To be or not to be...”*

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Using the information from http://nshipster.com/nslocale/:

```
let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
let qBegin = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleQuotationBeginDelimiterKey) as? String ?? "\""
let qEnd = locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleQuotationEndDelimiterKey) as? String ?? "\""

let quote = qBegin + "To be or not to be..." + qEnd
print(quote)
```

Sample results:

```
Locale   Output

 de      „To be or not to be...“
 en      “To be or not to be...”
 fr      «To be or not to be...»
 ja      「To be or not to be...」
```

I don't know if the begin/end delimiter key can be *undefined* for a
locale. In that case the above code would fall back to the normal
double-quote `"`.

Answer (score 12):

## Swift 4

Using the same logic, but with a modern and simple syntax.

```
extension String {
    static var quotes: (String, String) {
        guard
            let bQuote = Locale.current.quotationBeginDelimiter,
            let eQuote = Locale.current.quotationEndDelimiter
            else { return ("\"", "\"") }
        
        return (bQuote, eQuote)
    }
    
    var quoted: String {
        let (bQuote, eQuote) = String.quotes
        return bQuote + self + eQuote
    }
}
```

Then you can use it simply like this:

```
print("To be or not to be...".quoted)
```

Results

```
Locale   Output

 de      „To be or not to be...“
 en      “To be or not to be...”
 fr      «To be or not to be...»
 ja      「To be or not to be...」
```

Also, I advice you to read the whole Apple's [Internationalization and Localization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingLocaleData/InternationalizingLocaleData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH13-SW19)

Answer (score 0):

```
let quote = "\"To be or not to be...\""
println(quote)
```

output Will be:  "To be or not to be..."

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that seems straightforward but it does not localize.

Comment: Please see the Wikipedia link provided in the question showing quotation mark styles in different languages.

Comment: That's simple quotes. Real texts use different [smart quotes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/smart_quotes) for different languages. For example in Chinese/Japanese 「文字 To be or not to be...」

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Good point ("engineer's quotes" are not quite correct even for English locales). Martin's answer addresses this.

Comment: Why do people continue upvoting this while it doesn't answer the question? The locale requirement was already stated