# Regex with single quote (') not validating single quote

Tags: swift, regex

I'm using the following regex to validate the name:

```
> ^[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z.' ]{1,20}$
```

The single quote is mentioned in the second range. However, when I validate a string against this regex, the single quote (') invalidates the match. Here's my code:

```
let nameRegEx = "^[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z.' ]{1,21}$"
let nameTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", nameRegEx)
let isNameValid = nameTest.evaluate(with: name)
```

I've tried `\'` but no use.

Comment: Are you sure `name` contains a `'` and not some `&apos;`? If `let nameRegEx = "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9;#&.' ]{1,21}$"` works, then your string contains encoded text. Also note your regex matches at least 2 char strings, if you need to also match 1 char strings, replace `{1,21}` with `{0,21}`.

Comment: I'm comparing against `textField.text` property. Console shows regex as `"^[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z.\' ]{1,21}$"`

Comment: The problem is not with `nameRegEx`, but what `name` holds.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 7):

Turns out `textField.text` returns `’` and not `'`. Changing the character resolved the issue.

Comment: This helped me and my team member (working on entirely different module). I still don't know why same key return 2 different characters.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/31137195/3832970 answer. Looks like in your case, quotes got localized based on the current locale.